# Why Sliding Menu Can't Close in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, error-handling, slidingmenu

Please I have a problem, in my code like its nothing wrong, why when I select content on Sliding Menu, Sliding menus are not automatically covered? What's wrong with my code? I do not use a fragment only uses a switch to display the menu

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mDrawerItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    mDrawerItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer oepns
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,  GravityCompat.START);

    // Add items to the ListView
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mDrawerItems));
    // Set the OnItemClickListener so something happens when a 
    // user clicks on an item.
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, 
            mDrawerLayout, 
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
            R.string.drawer_open, 
            R.string.drawer_close
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    // Set the default content area to item 0
    // when the app opens for the first time
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        navigateTo(0);
    }

}

/*
 * If you do not have any menus, you still need this function
 * in order to open or close the NavigationDrawer when the user 
 * clicking the ActionBar app icon.
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about:
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, tentang.class);
         startActivity(i);
    }

    if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/*
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during onPostCreate()
 * and onConfigurationChanged()
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.v(TAG, "ponies");
        navigateTo(position);
    }
}

private void navigateTo(int position) {
    Log.v(TAG, "List View Item: " + position);

    switch(position) {
    case 0:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    sejarah.newInstance(),
                    sejarah.sejarah).commit();
        break;
    case 1:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    pakaian.newInstance(),
                    pakaian.pakaian).commit();
        break;
    case 2:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    rumah.newInstance(),
                    rumah.rumah).commit();
        break;
    case 3:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    senjata.newInstance(),
                    senjata.senjata).commit();
        break;
    case 4:
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, lagu.class);
         startActivity(i);
        break;
    case 5:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    musik.newInstance(),
                    musik.musik).commit();
        break;
    case 6:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    kesenian.newInstance(),
                    kesenian.kesenian).commit();
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you miss the the part **drawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerList) or mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList)**

Comment: where I have to put that code? please help me, I'm confused @santalu

Comment: when you clicked the menu item is it displaying the content?

Comment: while sliding content menu in the menu is selected, but the sliding menu is still open, not closed automatically, still be in front of the content @santalu

Comment: can you try getSlidingMenu().showContent(); when you clicked the menu item

Comment: wait a minute are you using navigation drawer or sliding menu?

Comment: navigation drawer @santalu , please help me

Comment: try drawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerList) or mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList) on item click